# Internal inconsistencies in storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

As i navigate to storyboard, i always get pop up as the image attached. I have checked if those images were missing but they are present and are in project folder too.  What should be done to get rid of these pop ups?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Are the photos present in the main asset catalog? Verify that in the asset catalog the images are listed without the extension like `*.jpg` or `*.png`

Comment: yeah they are present in Assets.xcassets. Yeah they don't have those extensions.